# Combining cells in R, LaTex

Tags: r, latex

Can I have two summary statistics in one cell in R-generated LaTex tables? I'm using the `tables` package and I'd like to summarize a column as `mean (sd)`. Here's a reproducible example in rmarkdown.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tables)
library(dplyr)
```

```{r table, results='asis'}
seed <- 1
iris2 <- iris %>% mutate(Region = factor(sample(c('East', 'West', 'Central'), 150, replace = TRUE)))
tabular((Species + 1) ~ (Region + 1) * Sepal.Length * (mean + sd),
        data = iris2) %>%
  latex %>%
  print
```
````

The output looks like this: [image: LaTex Table]

But I want the cells to look like e.g. 5.037 (0.3041). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something you want using paste()

E.g.:

```
paste(round(mean[1], digits=3), "(", sd[1], ")", collapse="")
```

Comment: I don't see how that would work in the call to tabular

Answer (score 0):

The Paste pseudo-function does the trick, but introduces unnecessary padding (see: [Remove padding from pasted cells in LaTex, R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516300/remove-padding-from-pasted-cells-in-latex-r)). Example code:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tables)
library(dplyr)
```

```{r table, results='asis'}
seed <- 1
iris2 <- iris %>% mutate(Region = factor(sample(c('East', 'West', 'Central'), 150, replace = TRUE)))
tabular((Species + 1) ~ (Region + 1) * Sepal.Length * Paste(Percent(), length, sep = '\\% (', postfix = ')'),
        data = iris2) %>%
  latex %>%
  print
```
````