# Remove padding from pasted cells in LaTex, R

Tags: r, latex

The Paste pseudo-function in the `tables` package combines cell values, but it also introduces unnecessary padding. See this example:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tables)
library(dplyr)
```

```{r table, results='asis'}
seed <- 1
iris2 <- iris %>% mutate(Region = factor(sample(c('East', 'West', 'Central'), 150, replace = TRUE)))
tabular((Species + 1) ~ (Region + 1) * Sepal.Length * Paste(Percent(), length, sep = '\\% (', postfix = ')'),
        data = iris2) %>%
  latex %>%
  print
```
````

[image]

Notice the padding inside the parentheses. How do I get rid of that?

Comment: if you used set.seed(1) rather than seed <- 1 it would be easier to debug this so we could get exactly your results